# Modifying labels in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am able to create the following *boxplot* using *gnuplot*.

[image]

However, I want the *xtic* labels to be of the form *log(x)*.

For instance, label 2 would be written as log(100), 3 as log(1000) and so on.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Not the ideal solution, but you can place tics explicitly, see [the docs](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html)

Comment: That might work. But I was hoping for the labels to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do that manually using `set xtics (...)`:

```
set xtics ('log(1)' 0, 'log(10)' 1, 'log(100)' 2, 'log(100)' 3)
```

to have this automated a bit, you can loop over your x-values:

```
set xtics ('log(1)' 0)
set for [i=1:5] xtics add (sprintf("log(%d)", 10**i) i)
```

Something like

```
set xtics format "log(...)"
```

doesn't work. This uses the same syntax like `gprintf`, which allows to extract several information of the given tic values (like mantissa, power, scientific power, hex, octal, multiple of pi etc), but not to perform mathematical operations on the values (`10**(ticvalue)`) and use the result for the visualization.

Comment: Thanks! This would work. I didn't know that it couldn't be automated.